# System.InvalidOperationException: "Для обновления требуется действительный UpdateCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с измененными строками

Tags: c#, access, forms

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace UspevStud
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public static string podkuchenie = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = student1.mdb";
        private OleDbConnection myconnection;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myconnection = new OleDbConnection(podkuchenie);
            myconnection.Open();

        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ballTableAdapter.Fill(this.student1DataSet.Ball);
            this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.student1DataSet.Student);
            this.grupTableAdapter.Fill(this.student1DataSet.Grup);
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.ballTableAdapter.Update(this.student1DataSet); //не хочет изменять и удалять(если изменять то выдает ошибку) запись ,только добавляет новую
        }

        private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myconnection.Close();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите полный текст ошибки в самом вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Нашел почему я могу только добавлять а не могу изменять и удалять. Во всем виноват один файл, где нет прописи Update и Delet. Всему виной (название БД) Designer.cs.